# Execute python script from Assembly

Tags: python, assembly, operating-system

I am planning on making an OS from scratch using **Python**. However I only know how to make it by writing in **Assembly.**

---

Is it possible for me to still **write the kernel in Assembly,** convert it to a binary and during boot execute the Python script?

*I hope this made sense*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would be interested in this project:

https://github.com/Maratyszcza/PeachPy

A comment from LtU:

> PeachPy is a Python framework for writing high-performance assembly kernels.
>
> PeachPy aims to simplify writing optimized assembly kernels while preserving all optimization opportunities of traditional assembly.
>
> You can use the same code to generate assembly for Windows, Unix, and Golang assembly. The library handles the various ABIs automatically. I haven't seen >this cool project before.
>
> Among the cool features is the ability to invoke the generated assembly as regular Python functions. Nice.

Comment: Perfect!! That was what I was looking for - glad you understood my question.